# Capacitor: deciphering the manufacturing code on a Ducati Energia capacitor

Tags: capacitor

I am a beginner who has resurrected various electronics with replacement parts without understanding in detail how they work.  Humbly, I would like to ask how a manufacturer code is broken down and whether it has any bearing on the product aside from the rest of its, recognizeable, specification.

I am looking to replace the ~25yo capacitor (shown) - [image: ~25yo fridge freezer capacitor]

Please would you explain the manufacturer code shown at the top "16.17.08.."?

The code for a "Ducati energia" capacitor available to [buy](https://uk.farnell.com/ducati/4-16-17-08-06/cap-5-f-450vac-5-pp-can/dp/2829385#) now (shown below), has in the description:-

"Manufacturer Part No: 4.16.17.08.06" - which prompted my question.

N.B. the "4.16" in the code as seen in the description looks to me like "416" in the photo (visible below), but the picture tag advises the photo is "for illustrative purposes only".

Thank you for taking my question.
[image: Ducati energia capacitor in 2023]

Comment: It's a fairly obscure part that would likely be best answered by the manufacturer. For instance, [this catalogue](https://www.ducatienergia.com/media/products/220509-1202-condensatori-motori-new.pdf) is probably a better source of information.

Comment: It looks like a standard motor start or run capacitor. Pretty much a generic part that you should be able to source from industrial motor suppliers, HVAC suppliers etc. As for decoding the part number the picture looks to be similar.

Comment: Thanks for taking the trouble to respond.
The Ducati energia catalogue linked by Andy aka is informative and groups the dot-separated numbers into categories.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than try to get the *identical* part, note the relevant ratings and get a part with similar or superior specifications. There are many sites to help you find the part, such as at [Mouser Electronics](https://www.mouser.com/c/passive-components/capacitors/?capacitance=5%20uF) or [Amazon](https://www.amazon.com/5-mfd-capacitor/s?k=5%20mfd%20capacitor).

Note that one repairing truly *antique* devices might want the identical appearance to an OEM part, and buy a modern replacement and covering it with the carefully-removed OEM shell. 25 years, though wouldn't be considered an antique.

The relevant specs:

- 5µF ±5%, which is a fairly tight range. Don't get a part with higher than ±5%
- 425 V - 500 V rating shows expected lifetime before failure. For safety, use a capacitor rated at 500 VAC, if you have not other information. You likely should  *not* use an electrolytic capacitor. (It's possible a non-polarized electrolytic cap might work, depending on its use, but they have a short life when exposed to AC, and quickly fall out of specifications.)
- -25 (°C) / 85 (°C) is the temperature rating, a common range for consumer-grade electronics.
- Note that physical size and mounting of the capacitor.

Comment: You taught me more than I asked, thank you DrMoishe Pippik.

Answer (score 0):

416.17.08 is a newer version of the same part it looks like. If you insist on replacing with a capacitor from the same manufacturer - you found the replacement.

Otherwise, follow the advice to replace based on specifications, size and fit, rather than same Make+Model.

> whether [the part number] has any bearing on the product aside from the rest of its, recognizeable, specification

Not really.

But do consider physical form to belong with the specification :)

Comment: Thank you -Kuba hasn't forgotten Monica-.  If curious, it is the original on our Hotpoint FFA90 fridge freezer.  So I'll take your/all advice here and get an equivalent/same that is good value including postage. 
I desired a little more knowledge on the subject and got a lot.  Thanks one and all.